# Truncated normal in WinBUGS

Tags: probability, bayesian, normal-distribution, bugs, truncation

I want to use the following truncated normal distribution in WinBUGS to estimate parameters of SEM using Bayesian analysis.

```
for(j in 1:P){y1[i,j]~djl.dnorm.trunc(mu1[i,j],psi1[j],thd[j,z1[i,j]],thd[j,z1[i,j]+1])}
```

I have a problem in that the last step in "updating tools," the updating tools are not responding.

After I also reduced the value of refresh from 100 to 1 at iteration 1, the updating tools stopped. How can I solve this problem? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like it might be more of a software issue than a statistical one, is this possible? If so, this forum might not be the best place to ask such a question. Have you searched WinBUGS's manual, or some WinBUGS-specific forum?